# Centrifugal force affecting satellite

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics

I'm trying to explain the behaviour of a geostationary satellite using different frames of reference.

1. **Inertial frame:** The satellite has a circular motion with angular velocity $\omega$. The centripetal force $F$ required for this motion is created by the gravitational pull of Earth. Earth itself rotates around its axis with $\omega$, but that is irrelevant. **OK**
2. **Rotating frame ($\omega$):** The frame of reference is fixed to Earth. Everything appears stationary. Gravity is still present, which still acts on the satellite with force $F$. Due to the acceleration of our frame of reference we introduce a centrifugal force, which acts on the satellite with $-F$. The forces cancel out, so the satellite's lack of acceleration is explained. **OK**
3. **Rotating frame ($2\omega$):** This frame of reference rotates around Earth's axis with angular velocity $2\omega$. The satellite appears to have angular velocity $-\omega$. The centripetal force $F$ is provided by gravity. However, we have not yet accounted for the acceleration of our frame of reference! There should be a centrifugal force of $-2F$, meaning that the satellite should be accelerating away from Earth!
   **Not OK**

How do we explain case 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is the [*coriolis force*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_effect#Formula).

The coriolis force is $F_c = -2m\Omega \times v $. Here $\Omega$ is the rotation of the frame of reference and $v$ is the linear speed of the satellite.

If you do the calculations, left as an exercies for the reader, you'll get the missing force.

In case 2 the coriolis force is 0, because the velocity $v$ has to be used in the local frame of reference. And there $ v = 0 $.

Comment: Note - Coriolis force is a "fictional" force that appears on moving objects in rotating frames of reference - which is why you didn't need it for either case 1 or 2 (1 = stationary frame, and 2 = stationary satellite).

Comment: @Floris: Like centrifugal force. But note that in case 2 (I've just added a note) the frame of reference is rotating; there is no coriolis force because $v=0$,

Comment: It might be "cleaner" to state that the Coriolis force is always there - but since it involves the product of $v$ and $\Omega$ it will be zero if either of them is zero. This is why you can get the right answer for case 1 and 2 without knowing about it. But on the whole, good answer - this is the explanation.